# Need help writing if else statement requiring specific keywords in dev c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, calendar, dev-c++

For my computer programming class they are requiring me to have someone input a date and for me to respond if it’s a real date or not Something like "September 10" would be a valid date; "triangle 44" would not and be met with the text “not valid”.

I’m trying to figure out why I can’t add multiple keywords to a if else statement so that **if** they put in one of the 12 months it would accept that, or **else** it would say it’s a not valid date. We use dev c++ if thats important.

For some reason whenever I add the months into the `if (month=="sept")` it will never go through the else statement even though I put in the wrong answer. I've even use `||` operators. I don't know what to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string month, VD;
    cout<<"Please state name of month you wish to leave: ";
    cin>>month;
if(month=="sept"){
    cout<<"true";
}
else{
    cout<<"false";
}
    //"September","October","November","December","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August"--months i need to add//
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (month == "sept" || month == "oct" || month == "nov")` or how did you try adding multiple months? However, just putting everything inside a big if-clause is usually not what is expected from students, and the whole point of the homework assignment is to teach you programming, not copy-pasting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.